# Fix Warning: Attempt to present ViewController on NavigationController whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller, uiwindow

Currently, I have set up a log-in view for users of my app. Below is the code that presents this log-in view to the user:

```
 // Handle how we present the view
    if (self.notificationToProcess != nil) {
        [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            SWNotificationsViewController *viewController = [[NotificationsViewController alloc] init];
            viewController.initialDataID = self.notificationToProcess[@"Data"];
            self.notificationToProcess = nil;

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
        }];
    } else if (self.detailURL != nil) {
        [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            WebViewController *wvc = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
            wvc.URL = self.detailURL;
            wvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
            [self.navigationController presentViewController:wvc animated:YES completion:nil];

            self.detailURL = nil;
        }];
    } else {
        [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

What I'm attempting to do now is display a web-view first if the user has just updated the app. Below is what this new code looks like:

```
// Handle how we present the view.
    if (self.notificationToProcess != nil) {
        [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            SWNotificationsViewController *viewController = [[SWNotificationsViewController alloc] init];
            viewController.initialDataID = self.notificationToProcess[@"Data"];
            self.notificationToProcess = nil;

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
        }];
    } else if (self.detailURL != nil) {
        [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            SWWebViewController *wvc = [[SWWebViewController alloc] init];
            wvc.URL = self.detailURL;
            wvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
            [self.navigationController presentViewController:wvc animated:YES completion:nil];

            self.detailURL = nil;
        }];
else if (![versionOfLastRun isEqual:currentVersion])
    {
        SWWebViewController *webViewController = [[SWWebViewController alloc] init];
        NSString *url=@"http://someurl";
        webViewController.URL = url;
        webViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:webViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:currentVersion forKey:@"VersionOfLastRun"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    }
    else if (versionOfLastRun == nil){
        // First start after installing the app
    }

    else {
        [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

However, when I run the app, the web view is not displayed, I get a warning of:

Warning: Attempt to present ViewController on NavigationController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Can anyone help me diagnose the problem? Thank you!

Comment: I'm actually working on an older project without a storyboard (everything is done programmatically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't call `self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^`

After correcting this (see listing below), my WebView was shown as expected.

```
else if (![versionOfLastRun isEqual:currentVersion])
    {
        [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            SWWebViewController *webViewController = [[SWWebViewController alloc] init];

            NSLog(@"%@", self.window.rootViewController);

            NSString *url=@"http://devstatwatch.drbsystems.com/releases_mobile.php";
            webViewController.URL = url;
            webViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
            [self.navigationController presentViewController:webViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:currentVersion forKey:@"VersionOfLastRun"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your viewController is not in Navigation controller hierarchy. This means that your controller is not connected with navigation controller stack which should handle presented controllers.

The other thing that should help is setting your root view controller as follows:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.ViewController;
```

EDIT: since you mention that you don't use storyboards, setting rootViewController should do the trick.

Comment: Hi Nick (my name too!), thanks for your reply. I added that line, but got the same result. I wonder if it's because this code is in my AppDelegate.m?

Comment: Which controller have you set for root? I have put ViewController as an example. Try setting wvc as your rootView controller(That is the one you want, right)

Comment: Yes, I did set wvc as the rootViewController, but Xcode still tells me that its's view isn't in the view hierarchy.

Comment: I added this line to see what the rootViewController's window as, and got a log of (null):         NSLog(@"%@", self.window.rootViewController);

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the window's rootViewController to the navigation controller after you initialize the navigation controller:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainController];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

This is how I'm doing it without storyboards.